# Unable to retrieve data from SQLite DB on SD Card on WP8

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, sd-card

I've created a SQLite DB using System.Data.SQLite in a console app. I've then moved this to the Windows Phone's SD card.

I followed these instructions to add SQLite support to my WP8 app:
https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8

I locate the DB file and open it like so:

```
ExternalStorageFile file = null;    
IEnumerable<ExternalStorageDevice> storageDevices = await ExternalStorage.GetExternalStorageDevicesAsync();
    foreach (ExternalStorageDevice storageDevice in storageDevices)
    {
        try
        {
            file = await storageDevice.GetFileAsync("northisland.nztopomap");
        }
        catch
        {
            file = null;
        }
        if (file != null) break;
    }

    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + file.Path + ";Version=3;Read Only=True;FailIfMissing=True;");

    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(_dbNorthIsland);
    command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tiles";
    int count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar<int>();
```

This results in the following error:

```
{SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: tiles
   at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2(Database db, String query)
   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare()
   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar[T]()}
```

Interestingly, I've also tried the following SQL statement:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"
```

Which gives a result of 0 suggesting my "tiles" table cannot be found?

I suspect that ExternalStorageFile.Path is returning a path that SQLite is unable to resolve as an existing file, leading it to create a new database and so complain about the missing table when I try to access it.

This Microsoft article seems to suggest that I should be able to access files from the SD card from my app:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

**Feedback provided by a Microsoft Employee:**

Your app doesn't have direct access to the files on the SD card. It can't open them directly with file system API, but needs to use the ExternalStorageFile and ExternalStorageFolder interfaces from Windows.Storage. To quote from Reading from the SD card on Windows Phone 8:

> Windows Phone apps can read specific file types from the SD card using
>   the Microsoft.Phone.Storage APIs.

I expect that the SQLite implementation for the phone tries to open the database using standard C file API rather than using the Storage objects and so requires that the database be in the Xap or isolated storage and cannot access a database on the SD card (this is definitely the case for SQLite for Windows Store apps).

In theory it would be possible to update SQLite to use Storage objects, but I suspect it would be a significant project to do so.

**Example bare-bones project:**

I've created a bare-bones example project that highlights my issue, just in case anyone wants to look and potentially try out any ideas quickly:

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=de82af8533ac6d28&id=DE82AF8533AC6D28!242&ithint=file,.zip&authkey=!AF4IwcI0G7bsDFE

Copy the bx24.nztopomap file to the root of your SD card to test.

**Feedback from SQLite SDK community:**

Apparently it should be fairly straight forward to add support to the SQLite SDK for someone with some C++ skills (mine are a bit rusty!):

Replies:
http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg81059.html
http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg81060.html

To my original question:
http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg81055.html

*Anyone know of a SQLite library for Windows Phone that can read from the SD card?*

Comment: Wild guess: are you absolutely sure that the file you copied onto the sd card is the exact same one you're looking at with your db explorer? More times that I'd like to admit, i copied files from DEBUG instead of RELEASE or vice versa, or had "do not copy" set and worked with old versions instead of the ones I just changed and so on and so forth.

Comment: @Corak - Yep, 100% sure as I have no empty versions ;)

Comment: Connection strings aside, can your app access the folder and file on external storage?

Comment: It can find it, as in I can get an ExternalStorageFile reference to it, but I've not been able to open it and retrieve data from it.

Comment: @JeremyCook - I tried using a FileStream to access the file and get a "Access to the path 'D:\bx24.nztopomap' is denied." error, so I guess the OS is blocking access to the location for my app. This Microsoft article seems to suggest I should be able to get access at files on the SD card though - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Bounty will be awarded to anyone who can point me in the direction of a SQLite library for Windows Phone 8 that can be used to access a DB read-only file on the SD card.

Comment: Just to rule it out: you have setup the file association in the app manifest?

Comment: Have you come to a solution for this problem?

Comment: @Hyndrix - Not really, but the problem sort-of went away with Windows Phone 8.1 as the user has the option of installing apps on the SD card now. If app is on SD card then the database can also exist on the SD card.

Comment: That's a good idea. Another way is to implement a virtual file system (I did this once but failed). Luckily someone went this path as way (I have not tested the implementation yet but it looks promising): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/879846/Using-SQLite-Databases-in-Any-Folder-in-WinRT

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a library for read-only access, you just need to register the files extension in a manifest. That might look something like this:

```
<Extensions>
   <FileTypeAssociation Name="SQLite"
                        TaskID="_default"
                        NavUriFragment="fileToken=%s">
       <Logos>
           <Logo Size="small" IsRelative="true">...</Logo>
           <Logo Size="medium" IsRelative="true">...</Logo>
           <Logo Size="large" IsRelative="true">...</Logo>
       </Logos>
       <SupportedFileTypes>
         <FileType ContentType="application/sqlite">.sqlite</FileType>
       </SupportedFileTypes>
   </FileTypeAssociation>
</Extensions>
```

Comment: I've done this - the problem seems to be in the way the SQLite SDK is trying to read the file on the SD card. See the "Feedback provided by a Microsoft Employee" part at the end of my question. Here's also a test project I knocked together previously which includes what you suggest(if you'd like to have a play) - https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=de82af8533ac6d28&id=DE82AF8533AC6D28!242&ithint=file,.zip&authkey=!AF4IwcI0G7bsDFE